# Node + Express Mongoose Sub Collection Document Insert

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a Node + Express project running, I am building a basic blogging system with the following Schema and Models

```
var Post = mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    body: String,
    author: String,
    dateCreated: {type: Date, default: Date.now },
    comments: [{author: String, body: String, date: Date}]
});
var Post = db.model('Post', Post);
```

I accept a post request via the following code and update the Title, Body and Author from it

```
app.post('/addpost', function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body.post);
    var post = new Post(req.body.post);
    post.save(function(err){
        if(!err){
            res.redirect('/');
        }else{
            res.redirect('/');
        }
    })
})
```

The question I have is, how do I add Comments to the schema using the coda I have already developed?

`req.body.post` outputs

```
{ title: 'Hello World', body: 'This is a body', author: 'Bioshox' }
```

Which is obviously acceptable for Mongoose, but in order to add comments how would I go about this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the following code snippet:

```
var comment = {
    author: req.body.post.author , 
    body: req.body.post.body, 
    date: new Date()
};

Post.findOneAndUpdate(
  { title: req.body.post.title },
  { $push: { comments: comment }},
  { safe: true, upsert: true },
  function(err, blogModels) {
    // Handle err
  });
```

This snippet simply try to find a `Blog` post, if it success then `$push` a new comment, otherwise, adds a blog post with a initial comment. So, your final code should look like this :

```
app.post('/addpost', function(req,res) {
    var comment = {
        author: req.body.post.author , 
        body: req.body.post.body, 
        date: new Date()
    };

    Post.findOneAndUpdate(
      { title: req.body.post.title },
      { $push: { comments: comment }},
      { safe: true, upsert: true },
      function(err, blogModels) {
        // Handle err
        });
});
```

Comment: if the `upsert` property is `true`, then mongo first try to find the document with the matching `title: req.body.post.title` criteria. If so, just update the document with the `{$push...}`. Otherwise, mongo creates a new document, insert it and $push the first comment init.

more information : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/

Comment: Actually I think upsert looks to find a **Post** with that title and if it doesn't exist creates the Post not the comment